# R syntax for Seurat ClassifyCells command

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I am working with an R package called `Seurat` for single cell RNA-Seq analysis.  I want to use a function of the package called `ClassifyCells` to add information about my various cell types to the data.  But I am struggling to get the syntax correct without an example.

**Here are the arguments for ClassifyCells:**

- object: `Seurat` object on which to train the classifier
- classifier: Random Forest classifier from `BuildRFClassifier`. If not provided, it will be built from the training data provided.
- training.genes    : Vector of genes to build the classifier on
- training.classes: Vector of classes to build the classifier on
- new.data  : New data to classify
- ...    additional parameters passed to ranger

**Here is the ClassifyCells command usage:**

```
ClassifyCells(object, classifier, training.genes = NULL, 
training.classes = NULL, new.data = NULL, ...)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
ClassifyCells(SeuratObject, Treated, 
              Training.genes = NULL, 
              Training.classes = cell1, cell2)
```

Perhaps what I am most confused by is how to refer to the cells which i want to include in the classification?  Do I do that in the training.classes section by using the column header labels from the table that was imported as the `seurat` object?

This code returns the following error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘ClassifyCells’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Thanks for your help!